# Linked List in c add to front

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I'm really confused.  I am trying to write a c method that allows me to add a new "node" to the front of a linked list.  I have done this before in c++ and no problem.  I am getting frustrated because after writing code I was pretty sure was right I went and looked around and basically everywhere I find tells me to do the same thing I am all ready doing...I'll provide code and step by step addresses and values of the variables.  Here is the code:

The real function in question is:

```
void addToBeginning(int value, struct node* root){
    struct node* newNode;
    newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = root;
    root = newNode;
}
```

But here is the complete code. I removed some things to make it more concise (things that aren't necessary to answer this question like getLength(...) and addToPos(...))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};

void printLinkedList(struct node* root);

void addToEnd(int value, struct node* root);

void addToBeginning(int value, struct node* root);

void addToPos(int pos, int value, struct node* root);

int getLength(struct node* root);


int main(){        
    /**
     TESTING addToBeginning (I know addToEnd works)
     **/

    struct node *root2;
    root2 = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
    root2->value = 4;
    root2->next = NULL;

    /*
     root2 = 4 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0
     */
    i = 0;
    while (i < 5){
        addToEnd(0,root2);
        i++;
    }

    printLinkedList(root2);
    //printf("Length : %d\n",getLength(root2));

    /*
     expected root2 = 2 -> 4 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0
     */
    addToBeginning(2, root2);
    printLinkedList(root2);
    /*
     obtained root2 = 4 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 0
     */
    //printf("Length : %d\n",getLength(root2));

    return(0);
}

void printLinkedList(struct node* root){
    while(root != NULL){
        if (root->next != NULL){
            printf("%d, ",root->value);
            root=root->next;
        } else {
            printf("%d\n",root->value);
            root=root->next;
        }
    }

}

void addToEnd(int value, struct node* root){
    /*
     Set up new node
     */
    struct node* newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    /*
     Check if empty linked list first
     */
    if (root->next == NULL){
        root->next = newNode;
    } else {
        /*
         Find the last node
         */
        struct node* current = root;
        while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}

void addToBeginning(int value, struct node* root){
    struct node* newNode;
    newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = root;
    root = newNode;
}
```

What is so confusing is I feel that there is a problem with aliasing at the

```
newNode->next = root;
root = newNode;
```

lines...so I am including the addresses obtained during my debug steps:
So...within the `addToBeginning(int value, struct node* root){...}` function I'm going to go through step by step:

after execution of:

```
struct node* newNode;
newNode = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
```

the addresses and values of root and newNode are:

```
root = 0x0000000100103c60
root->next = 0x0000000100103c70
root->value = 4
newNode = 0x0000000100103cc0
newNode->next = NULL
newNode->value = 0
```

after execution of:

```
newNode->value = value;
```

the addresses and values of root and newNode are:

```
root = 0x0000000100103c60
root->next = 0x0000000100103c70
root->value = 4
newNode = 0x0000000100103cc0
newNode->next = NULL
newNode->value = 2
```

after execution of:

```
newNode->next = root;
```

the addresses and values of root and newNode are:

```
root = 0x0000000100103c60
root->next = 0x0000000100103c70
root->value = 4
newNode = 0x0000000100103cc0
newNode->next = 0x0000000100103c60
newNode->value = 2
```

after execution of:

```
root = newNode;
```

the addresses and values of root and newNode are:

```
root = 0x0000000100103cc0
root->next = 0x0000000100103c60
root->value = 2
newNode = 0x0000000100103cc0
newNode->next = 0x0000000100103c60
newNode->value = 2
```

I realize that the problem is that `*root` is passed by reference so what I need to do is change the value of the object stored in the location `0x0000000100103c60` so any suggestions on how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: You modify the local copy of `root` in the insert function; you don't modify the corresponding value in the calling code.  Either return the new head of the list from the function, or pass a pointer to the pointer to the root node to the function so that the pointer to the root node can be modified in the function.  There are lots, and lots, of questions like this with the same basic problem here on SO.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you @JonathanLeffler a pointer to the pointer is all I needed to hear!

Comment: OMG!!!  A linked-list question with debugging steps explained!  Have an upvote.  I gotta got get a lottery ticket.

Comment: Note that the code in `main()` to create a node is `struct node *root2;
    root2 = malloc( sizeof(struct node));
    root2->value = 4;
    root2->next = NULL;` and there is almost identical code in your `addToBeginning()` and `addToEnd()` code.  This should probably be abstracted out into a `struct node *newElement(int value);` function.  You can then add error checking for a `malloc()` failure in one place, rather than having to do it in three different places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function

```
void addToBeginning(int value, struct node* root){
    struct node* newNode;
    (...)
    root = newNode;
}

struct node *root2;
addToBeginning(2, root2);
```

you assign new address to the local root pointer. This pointer has the same value as your original root pointer but it is a copy of it. So changing that variable inside your function has no effect on original root after function returns.

Instead you have to pass pointer by pointer:

```
void addToBeginning(int value, struct node **root){
    struct node* newNode;
    (...)
    *root = newNode;
}

struct node *root2;
addToBeginning(2, &root2);
```

---

### Additional information

It might be surprising. Didn't you always pass to the function the pointer when you wanted to change the original variable? Well, yes, but then it was variable being pointed to - not the pointer itself. Here, assuming your original function taking a pointer (not pointer to pointer) you could have still changed the original node being pointed by root2 with `*root2 = x` or the members of that node with `root2->member = y`. It would work because you change the variable being pointed to (even if they are pointers - you can change these pointers [the addresses they are pointing to] because you have a pointer to them and you dereference that pointer).

The same applies to the pointer as a variable. If you want to change the original pointer you have to point to it and change the variable being pointed to, in that case original pointer.

Comment: Exactly and pass root as &root

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
void addToBeginning(int value, struct node** root)
```

Note two `*` for `root`

This allows you to modify `root` outside of this function.